# ngFor does not load the dynamically populated array on NavigationEnd event Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Having problem displaying array with ngFor on NavigationEnd Event, in the constructor of my class

```
testArray = [];

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.forEach(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.testArray = [1, 2, 3,4];
        }
    });
}


<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li *ngFor="let element of testArray"
        class="breadcrumb-item">
        {{element}}
    </li>
</ol>
```

Even though the array is populated when the NavigationEnd event happens, it does not display the contents of the array. The html page does not seem to reload with new Array data. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work when I try it in a StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5txgvo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i am using angular ~7.0.4. could it be the version?

Comment: Unlikely, that StackBlitz is using 7.0.1, so pretty much the same. If you add a `console.log` inside that `forEach`, is it being printed?

Comment: it does print console.log but no html. My component is a nested element. will make a difference?

Comment: Are you able to copy the minimal code necessary to reproduce into a StackBlitz please?

Comment: component also seems to work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vx3h27?file=src%2Fapp%2FTestComponent%2Fapp-bread-crumbs%2Fapp-bread-crumbs.component.html

Comment: i have some routing to the component that may be an issue

Comment: Without the information necessary to reproduce the problem, there's not a lot we can do to help

Comment: thanks for your help seems to work if move it in the parent component something local to my setup

Answer (score 0):

> Use `setTimeout` while setting the value.

```
   testArray = [];
       constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.forEach(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
           this.testArray = [1, 2, 3,4];
        });

      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you use async pipe here

```
testArray: Observable<number[]>;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    testArray = this.router.events.pipe(filter(event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).map(() => [1, 2, 3,4])
}

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li *ngFor="let element of testArray | async" class="breadcrumb-item">
        {{element}}
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: still same <ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li *ngFor="let element of testArray | async"
      class="breadcrumb-item">
       {{element}}
  </li>
</ol>

Comment: this.testArray = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => [1, 2, 3,4]));

Answer (score 0):

The view seems to be loaded before the array population. You can try to make your class implement "OnInit" available from "@angular/core" and make the foreach on "ngOnInit" method :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.forEach(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.testArray = [1, 2, 3,4];
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        //calls this stuff when navigation ends
        this.testArray = [1, 2, 3,4];
        
      }
    });
  }